# arrays and foreach loops to work with input vars more efficiently

Tags: php, variables

If I have 20 user input vars and want to work between $var[0..19], $_SESSION['var'[0..19]], & $_POST['var'[0..19]], such as:

```
$var0 = $_SESSION['var0'] = $_POST['var0'];
```

How could I do this efficiently using arrays and foreach loops?

**Additional details:**

So initially I have been thinking to try something like:

```
$inputVars = array('var1'=>$var1, 'var2'=>$var2, 'var3'=>$var3, 'var4'=>$var4, 'var5'=>$var5)

$inputVarsS = array($_SESSION['inputVars = array('svar1'=>$_SESSION['var1']'], 'svar2'=>$_SESSION['var2'], 'svar3'=>$_SESSION['var3'], 'svar4'=>$_SESSION['var4'], 'svar5'=>$_SESSION['var5'])

$inputVarsP = array($_POST['inputVars = array('pvar1'=>$_POST['pvar1']'], 'pvar2'=>$_POST['pvar2'], 'pvar3'=>$_POST['pvar3'], 'pvar4'=>$_POST['pvar4'], 'pvar5'=>$_POST['pvar5'])
```

and then I guess I could do something like:

```
$inputVarsS['svar1'] = $inputVarsP['pvar1'];
```

to set session value svar1 to posted value pvar1. But I am thinking there really must be a more efficient way to do these kinds of assignments.

I think I could just easily have $inputVars array and assign either POST SESSION values to the keys, but what if I want to have POST and SESSION values available simultaneously? Then I assume I need multiple arrays?

Comment: `foreach($var as $k=>$v) { ...  $var[$k] ... $_SESSION['var'.$k] ... $_POST['var'.$k] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $$ to define a variable name, but I think it's better to use an array $vars.

With $var0, $var1, ...., and you can access them like `echo $var4`

```
foreach(range(0, 19) as $index)
{
  $var = 'var' . $index;
  $$var = $_SESSION[$var] = $_POST[$var];
}
```

With array $vars, and access them with `echo $vars[4]`

```
foreach(range(0, 19) as $index)
{
  $var = 'var' . $index;
  $vars[$var] = $_SESSION[$var] = $_POST[$var];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks information, so my answer can be wrong.

You can copy an whole array like this:

```
$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
```

Then when you want to extract variables from that, you can use:

```
extract($_SESSION['post']);
```

So if `$_POST['var0']` exists it will extract `$var0`.

However, you should NEVER put posted data in global scope. Hackers can use this to inject their variables into your code. Please always filter input first. A bit better is this:

```
extract($_SESSION['post'],EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,'post');
```

So it will be `$post_var0` instead of `$var0`. But still, make sure you only get the variables you want, and filter their values.